# ICONS HTML EMAIL

Tags: html, css, email, icons

I am creating HTML Emails and I have an issue with aligning the social media icons horizontally to the center without there being a ton of spacing between them. I have tried everything but I can't seem to get rid of the spaces.

```html
<table style="cellspacing:0;cellpadding:0;border:0;border-spacing:-90px;">
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color:#ffffff;font-size:0;justify-content:center;">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/ryZdj57h/facebook-solidblack.png" alt="facebook icon"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/3xbgVPyv/instagram-solidblack.png" alt="instagram icon"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/nLjwPKLn/twitter-solidblack.png" alt="twitter icon"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: I tried to post it but it wouldn't allow me because it has a photo src link and I guess I need to post 10 times before I can post photo links

Comment: Photo links? Just include your code in the question directly using the triple backquote ``` which creates a code block

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways of centering `table` tags in `HTML`, but the simplest way of accomplishing this is to set the left and right margins to `auto`.

```html
<table style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
  <tr>
   <td>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/ryZdj57h/facebook-solidblack.png" alt="facebook icon"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/3xbgVPyv/instagram-solidblack.png" alt="instagram icon"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/nLjwPKLn/twitter-solidblack.png" alt="twitter icon"></a>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I also highly suggest you to use seperate `CSS` stylesheets. this way you can organize and group your `CSS` files properly in development. you can do this by including a css file in your `HTML` `head` tag like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

**Note!** Please note that the `href` attribute shoud be set to the path and name of your own `CSS` file!